# How to derive the short cut version of variance calculation for probability distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, variance

How to derive from formula 2 to 3?

[image]

Comment: Just expand $(x - \mu)^2 = x^2 - 2x\mu + \mu^2$, and note $\sum xp(x) = \mu$.

Comment: This is a FAQ, but it's hard to search for the answers.  I estimate they appear in several dozen posts here, if not more.

Comment: @Student as a practical matter, beware that "easier for computations" version. While it is simpler and faster, it's numerically unstable and definitely not recommended for use unless you're working by hand and can (a) easily identify when there's catastrophic cancellation and (b) know exactly how to fix it. Otherwise, treat it as a potentially dangerous formula. To my astonishment at the time, Excel used this dangerous form for many, many years (it doesn't do that now though).